# not able to start nginx server at fedora22

Tags: linux, nginx, fedora

I am using fedora22 I have installed nginx server on it. It was running and working perfectly but any how it was stopped.
Now I am trying to start it  but it is not starting 
I tried following commaned

```
# service nginx restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  nginx.service
Job for nginx.service failed. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details

#systemctl start nginx
Job for nginx.service failed. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

but it is not starting how to start this??

```
#systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-09-01 11:12:12 UTC; 21h ago

Sep 01 11:12:12 www.mysite.com systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and rev....
Sep 01 11:12:12 www.mysite.com nginx[313]: nginx: [emerg] no port in upstr...7
Sep 01 11:12:12 www.mysite.com nginx[313]: nginx: configuration file /etc/...d
Sep 01 11:12:12 www.mysite.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process ...1
Sep 01 11:12:12 www.mysite.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP ....
Sep 01 11:12:12 www.mysite.com systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered fail....
Sep 01 11:12:12 www.mysite.com systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

`tail /var/log/nginx/error.log`
is showing

 `no port in upstream "php-fpm" in /etc/nginx/default.d/phpMyAdmin.conf:17`

Comment: First step would be to run the command its telling you to at least

Comment: @NooBskie please see update

Comment: I got this because one of my nginx site config files were pointing to the wrong path for the php-fpm socket file.  once i did "sudo systemctl status nginx.service -l" it pointed to the bad config file, fixed it and i was good.

Answer (score 3):

Probably php-fpm is not installed.

```
sudo dnf install php-fpm
```